# Change the kendo calendar month names from shortform to fullform

Tags: calendar, kendo-ui

In the kendo calendar control, the months names in the months view(where all the months of a specific year are listed) are shown in the short form instead of the full name. How can i change the names to full form only in this view. Ex: Mar instead of March.

I tried changing the date format using 'calendar.options.format' property, but it dosen't make any difference. Need help.

Comment: Are you using the `DatePicker` control? If so, have you had a look at the `format` option? See: [Kendo UI DatePicker usage](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datepicker/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The calendar widget is programmed to always use the month abbreviation names. However, you can edit these names in the Kendo culture settings. Just be aware that they will change anywhere in Kendo that uses month abbreviations.

The abbreviations are stored in:

```
kendo.cultures.current.calendars.standard.months.namesAbbr
```

which is an array, indexed by the month. So you could set:

```
kendo.cultures.current.calendars.standard.months.namesAbbr[0] = "January";
kendo.cultures.current.calendars.standard.months.namesAbbr[1] = "February";
// ...etc...
```

---

Or, to make things easier, you can just copy the entire un-abbreviated months array to the abbreviated array, instead of setting each individual month:

```
kendo.cultures.current.calendars.standard.months.namesAbbr = kendo.cultures.current.calendars.standard.months.names;
```

---

However, that is still going to affect any other Kendo widgets that rely on the month abbreviations. A cleaner approach would be to make a custom culture for the Calendars to use. So in the initialization script for your page, after you include kendo.min.js, you can do this:

```
// just do this once on page load. copy current culture to a new one, and replace abbreviated months.
kendo.cultures.currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations = $.extend(true, {}, kendo.cultures.current);
kendo.cultures.currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations.name = "currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations";
kendo.cultures.currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations.calendars.standard.months.namesAbbr = kendo.cultures.currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations.calendars.standard.months.names;
```

Then the calendar widgets that you want to use full month names in, you can tell it to use your custom culture.

```
$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    culture: "currentWithoutMonthAbbreviations"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Considering that the app supports multiple languages, it would be a problem to create and manage custom culture files. I was looking for some kind of configuration like changing the date format so that the calendar will start showing the names in full instead of abbreviations.

Comment: There is no setting available. The other options would be to replace `kendo.calendar.views[1].content` with a custom function of your own (copy/paste the existing function source code but change where it uses the abbreviation), or propose a setting as a new feature at http://feedback.kendoui.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this script for days. I imagine the same would work for months:

```
var dayInfo = kendo.culture().calendar.days;
for (var i = 0; i < dayInfo.namesAbbr.length; i++) {
    dayInfo.namesShort[i] =  dayInfo.namesAbbr[i];
}
```